# In AUTOSAR DEM ,retention of fault memory after re-programming

Tags: diagnostics, autosar

In AUTOSAR DEM ,what happens to fault memory if it saved in NVM in case of reprogramming ? Can the DTC information retained after re-programming ?

Answer (score 1):

During reprogramming (flashing) the NvM is usually not "touched", so the data can be retained. Even more: the OEM usually explicitly requires that the NvM retaines after reprogramming.
One thing you need to consider though is that the NvM layout must not change "dramatically" so that the newly flashed software can run with the existing (old) NvM layout. For that you also should enable the "ResistantToChangedSW" flag for the relevant NvM-Blocks.

Comment: Thank you oliver.. if user wants to erase NvM while reprogramming ,is it possible to do ?

Comment: You really should contact the supplier of your bootloader.

Comment: @user2538554 So far I only had the requirement to deny reprogramming if the fault memory was not cleared.
And correct configuration of the memory stack usually allows you to keep data if compatible.
However, for sure you can also forcefully delete/ ignore it.
Simplest way it to have the block IDs check on and assign new block IDs to all NVM blocks.
P.S.: This should be a different question in stackoverflow.